# 'Alternative' way to get notifications on stack exchange on Android

Tags: android, stack-exchange

I've been hanging on to the old SE android application - mainly for notifications.

The old one is out of support, *and* removed from the play store. I'm getting a new phone and might sideload the oldest version but I'm wondering if there's any alternative ways I can view and open up (preferably on a browser) my stack exchange notifications.

There were quite a few "pre" official app, but the only modern ones I can find on any platform are crew- which seems to be [IOS only](https://stackapps.com/questions/8839/crew-for-stack-full-native-client) and [stack](https://stackapps.com/questions/8753/stack-android-application) which is in an early but active state of development.

So what I'm looking for

- Push notifications for items in my stack exchange inbox on android
- currently updated and available on the official google play store

Nice to have

- Option to open things up in a browser, but a reliable SE android client clone would be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange has RSS feed capability. The variety of RSS feed readers is substantial, making it difficult to recommend a specific reader app. Most (possibly all, how to know?) readers provide an option to open a selected feed entry in a browser.

The difference between various reader apps will be how the feed is displayed, in terms of columns and summaries of posts, as well as the desired notification options.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding - I mean for things like my inbox. SE's app will send notifications for things like @s and comments that also turn up on your top bar inbox, like this comment will. I have edited my question to reflect that

Comment: I would consider to delete my answer, but feel that with your updated question, it may have value for others who are unaware of the RSS option. Thanks for the clarification.